# Python Selenium ChromeDriver Throws Chrome failed to start Error

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location = driver_path
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=driver_path)
```

The code above won't successfully run chromedriver, and its error message is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: was killed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location ${driver_path} is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

I saw some suggestions to set the folder that contains the driver file to path, but I do NOT wish to use the method, so I haven't tried it.

I've got no idea why the driver is killed. The driver is up-to-date, and the version matches with the Chrome Browser installed. The computer has extra RAM of 24GB, so it's unlikely to be a RAM problem. The weird thing is that the code works in my laptop, but does not in my desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the solution. Many solutions suggest the value of `options.binary_location` should be **ChromeDriver Path**, but it must be **Chrome Browser Binary Path**. So this just successed:

```py
options = Options()
options.binary_location = chrome_path
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=driver_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please confirm after removing the quotes
considering you have declared `driver_path`

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=driver_path)
```

Comment: Well that's just typo. I declared `driver_path` correctly. Sorry about the mistake

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a directory issue. try making driver_path a string where you copy the path of the web driver exe. Ex : r"C:\Users\Person\chromeWebDriver.exe"

User r"" to make sure it ignores the back slashes. Try to see if you can launch it with the direct path to find out if its a dir issue.

Comment: I DID use raw string. The error message doesn't say it cannot find the driver; it says the driver was killed.

Comment: Try "chrome_options - Options()" then "chrome_options.use_experimental_options("detach" = True)"